# HTML TO PDF conversion in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to convert Html template to pdf and I need to download that file. I am Using Angular 2. Is there any TypeScript code to convert HTML template to pdf?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Asking for code samples is off-topic.

Comment: There are also npm packages that you could probably use to help you achieve this.You could try taking a look at jspdf: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using an external library to be able to export documents from my Angular4 app : https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

It might not be exactly what you require for the whole page, but to extract data as CSV / PDF from my application it was perfect.

Here is the sample code I used to extract my data. I binded this method to a button to trigger the event :

```
exportDatas(documentType: string) {
  this.MyRandomServiceThatReturnsData.getDatas(MyParameters1, ...)
  .subscribe(result => {
    const blob = new Blob([result.blob()]);
    const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'Export.' + documentType);
  });
}
```

Comment: i am using angular 2 cli compiler. i want to convert html to pdf in front end. not from server side

Comment: This is from an Angular component

Comment: FileSaver doesn't convert the HTML to PDF though, right? Are you using something else to do that conversion?

Answer (score 0):

This suprisingly tricky when you want to create a PDF that looks exactly like an Angular HTML template with data filled in.  I use this a lot for reports as layout can be done in HTML and the user can either see it on-screen or print/save/email as PDF.

Thought a PDF printer driver would do it but that seems to only work for pages completed on the server side.

The solution I've found, which works flawlessly, is a commercial app, HiQPdf.  Works in C# and will do pretty much anything you want. Find it a cost-effective solution.  Wish I had known about it before I had blown off 20+ non-billable hours trying to accomplish it myself.